# alphabetize by background url

Tags: jquery

Trying to adapt this to alphabetize by a href url, instead of the a href text...

Javascript

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function (a, b) {
    var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
});
parent.append(items);
}

$(function () { sortUsingNestedText($('.searchresults'), "div", ".title a"); });
```

HTML

```
<div class="title"><a href="../url/thisiswhatiwantsorted/default.html">Link</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
```

to:

```
var vA = $(keySelector, a).attr("href");
var vB = $(keySelector, b).attr("href");
```

and sorting by the last part of the url:

```
var vAURL = $(keySelector, a).attr("href").split('/');
var vA = vAURL[vAURL.length-1];
var vBURL = $(keySelector, b).attr("href").split('/');
var vB = vBURL[vBURL.length-1];
```

Comment: that's possible by splitting with '/' and selecting the last element of the result.